# Error while solving differential equations matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm looking for way to solve this differential equations.

[image: equations]

I've got small experience solving this type of equations, so here's my noob code

```
function lab1()
[t,h]=ode45('threepoint', [0 1000], [0 0.25]);
plot(t, h);  

function f = threepoint(x, y)
%THREEPOINT Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
m = 15000;
R1 = 0.1;
R2 = 0.1;
P1 = 0.1;
P2 = 0.1;
B = 4;
rbk = 0.5;
f=[x(6);
    x(7);
    x(8);
    x(9);
    x(10);
    (-x(6) / (m * sqrt( x(6)*x(6) + x(7)*x(7)))) * (R1 + R2) + (cos(x(3))/m) * P1 + (cos(x(3))/m) * P2;
    (-x(7) / (m * sqrt( x(6)*x(6) + x(7)*x(7)))) * (R1 + R2) + (cos(x(3))/m) * P1 + (cos(x(3))/m) * P2;
    -(M/I) - (1/I1)* (B/2 + y(1))*P1 + (1/I2)*(B/2+y(2))*P2;
    (rbk/I1)*(P1-R1);
    (rbk/I2)*(P2-R2);
    ];  
end
```

While running these functions I have got such errors like

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in threepoint (line 11) f=[x(6);
>
> Error in odearguments (line 87) f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   %
>   ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.
>
> Error in ode45 (line 113) [neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir,
>   y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...
>
> Error in lab1 (line 2) [t,h]=ode45('threepoint', [0 1000], [0 0.25]);

Can anyone please show me where am I mistaken and how can I fix these errors?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Oh dear, please don't add error messages as images. Nor code (generally speaking). Use that copy+paste, please.

Comment: As for your question: look at the manual: `[TOUT,YOUT] = ode45(ODEFUN,TSPAN,Y0)`. Now look at your error. The time span has to be a vector, rather than 2 separate start/end values.

Comment: @AndrasDeak That's my bad, I've tried to write this code in different ways and finally paste the wrong one. I wrote like this [t,h]=ode45('threepoint', [0 1000], [0 0.25]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a close look at `help ode45`. I admit this part of the usage might not be clear, so take a look at `doc ode45` too.

Here's the essence of your problem. You want to solve a differential equation of 10 variables, each a function of `t`. So, how does a general solver like `ode45` know that it needs to work with 10-component arrays at each time step? From the only place it can: the initial value!

Here's how you're calling `ode45`:

```
[t,h]=ode45('threepoint', [0 1000], [0 0.25]);
```

The second array, `Y0`, is the initial value. This is clear from the docs. Since you're supplying a 2-element vector, `ode45` smartly realizes that you have only 2 equations. When you try to use `Y(6)` and other high-index values in `threepoint()`, you get the error you're getting: *Index exceeds matrix dimensions*. Because your index, `6`, exceeds the size of the array, which is `2`.

You always need to use initial values with the proper size (length-10 in your specific case) in order to inform the solver about the dimensions of your problem. Even if `ode45` could assert the size of your equations from somewhere, you *really have to provide* initial values for all 10 components of your solution.

Comment: Thank you, it seems more clear now. I've fixed code like this
function lab1()
[t,h]=ode45('threepoint', [1 2], [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]);
plot(t, h);

and now i got error 

Undefined function or variable 'y'.

But why is it undefined? I change function like this

function f = threepoint(y, x)

so y got  [1 2] and x got [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]?

Comment: @dimazava are you familiar with MATLAB?

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally I've solved these equations)

Comment: @dimazava I'm glad I could help.